# TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=256.0>)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, model

while saving the model by `model.save()` i got errors from these file
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSP6h.png)

can you provide information why these errors are shown

Comment: kindly see the error image and if possible tell me why i am getting errors code files are on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68205450/attributeerror-super-object-has-no-attribute-get-config

Comment: I'm guessing this is connected to the other two questions you posted in the last two days.  Please add the full code of the class you specify, including your implementation of `get_config`, which is likely the source of this error.

Comment: yes you are right i have given the link of code which include implementation of  `get_config` model training is perfectly done when i execute this line `model.save('chatbot_model')` it gave this error.